# Prove the existence of two prime numbers whose product is less that a given integer s.t. the following quantity is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, goldbachs-conjecture

I am working on understanding [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) and trying to make a small project on its various properties. Finally, I came up with the following statement,

"Let, $n>2$ be any natural number. Then there exist two prime numbers $p,q$ (not necessarily distinct) such that, $pq<n^2$ and $n^2-pq$ is a perfect square."

Can we prove it without assuming Goldbach's conjecture? Or is there any counterexample of my statement?

[Do not confuse with, [Can you prove or disprove the following list of my conjectures?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534361/can-you-prove-or-disprove-the-following-list-of-my-conjectures])

**Examples:**

For $n=3$ set $p=q=3$ we get $n^2-pq=0$ perfect square! [This case is special as here $n^2=pq$]

For $n=4$ set $p=5,q=3$ we get $n^2-pq=1$ perfect square!

For $n=5$ set $p=7,q=3$ we get $n^2-pq=4$ perfect square!

For $n=6$ set $p=5,q=7$ we get $n^2-pq=1$ perfect square! etc.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide some more concrete evidence why you would think the statement is true, apart from checking it in a few cases?

Comment: I am not sure about the truth-ness of my statement because it depends on something which is not proved yet. What type of concrete evidence do you need?

Comment: Take a look at this. It's not a proof but it shows how you set up the numbers to get $n^2=pq+y^2$ provided $y+p+y=q$ with $q>p$ and $p+q=2n$.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187713/can-the-solution-to-n2-pqy2-help-with-the-golbach-conjecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $2n>3$ be an even number. If there are primes $p\le q$ such that $n^2-pq$ is a perfect square, we have that
$$n^2-pq=m^2$$
That is
$$(n-m)(n+m)=pq$$
We have two possibilities:

**1**) $n+m=pq$ and $n-m=1$. This implies $2n=pq+1$.
**2**) $n+m=q$ and $n-m=p$. This implies $2n=p+q$.

So if your statement is true, the Goldbach's conjecture's statement would be true for every even number $2n$ such that $2n-1$ is not a product of two primes. It is not Goldbach's conjecture, but it is much more than what have been proved so far.

Comment: The link below provided a way to get the solutions for the equation $n^2-pq=m^2$. The number of solutions is $n$. All that is needed to prove is that among those $n$ solutions, there will always be at least one with a pair of primes (p,q).
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187713/can-the-solution-to-n2-pqy2-help-with-the-golbach-conjecture

Answer (score 3):

Your statement is **close to be equivalent** to the Goldbach Conjecture (GC).

Indeed if GC holds from 
$$
2n=p+q
$$
with $p$ and $q$ primes it follows that $n-p=q-n$ (call this quantity $b$) and next $n=p+b$ and $n=q-b$ which yields immediately
$$
n^2=pq-b^2
$$
which is what you propose here.

On the other hand if you manage to write 
$$
n^2-pq=b^2
$$
for primes $p\leq q$ and $b<n-1$ (i.e. $2n-1\neq pq$),
then $n^2-b^2=(n+b)(n-b)=pq$ and we have to conclude that
$n+b=q$ and $n-b=p$ since $p$ and $q$ are primes by the unique decomposition. But then
$$
2n=p+q
$$
proves GC for $2n$.

Comment: We can also have $n+b=pq$ and $n-b=1$.

Comment: @ajotatxe: Thanks for the observation. I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks to both of you for answering your views. So I conclude that my statement is equivalent to GC and is true iff GC is true.